# Xcode gives an error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml

My code is just simple c++ using SFML library.

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <array>
#include "board.h"

void Board::load(sf::Color col1, sf::Color col2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<8;i++)
    {
        bool tmpColor=((i%2)==0)?true:false;
        
        for(int j=0; j<8;j++)
        {
            m_boardSquares[j + (i * 8)].setPosition(sf::Vector2f( j*64.f , i*64.f ));
            m_boardSquares[j + (i * 8)].setSize(sf::Vector2f(64.f, 64.f));
            m_boardSquares[j + (i * 8)].setFillColor(tmpColor ? col1 : col2);
            tmpColor = !tmpColor;

        }
    }
}

void Board::draw(sf::RenderTarget& window, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++){
        window.draw(m_boardSquares[i]);
    }
}

int main(int, char const**)
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "Chess");
    window.setFramerateLimit(30);
        window.clear();
        b.load();
        void draw(sf::RenderTarget& window, sf::RenderStates states) ;
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**board.h**

```
#define board_h

class Board : public sf::Drawable{

public:

    Board(sf::Color col1 = sf::Color::White, sf::Color col2 = sf::Color::Black);
    
    // Member function that sets Board stuff, can choose square colors in parameters
    void load(sf::Color col1 = sf::Color::White, sf::Color col2 = sf::Color::Black);

public:

    std::array<sf::RectangleShape, 64> m_boardSquares;
    
    // Draw class on SFML Window
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& window, sf::RenderStates states) const;

};

#endif /* board_h */
```

and the error I get is "
Showing Recent Errors Only
Undefined symbol: Board::Board(sf::Color, sf::Color)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Board::Board(sf::Color, sf::Color)", referenced from:
__GLOBAL__sub_I_main.cpp in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
"

any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You have declared `Board::Board(sf::Color col1 = sf::Color::White, sf::Color col2 = sf::Color::Black);` but where is it defined ?

Comment: The code you show should give you plenty of errors before even coming to linking.

Comment: You define `Board::load` and `Board::draw`. But you never define the `Board` constructor (`Board::Board`) anywhere.